# Declaring variable as Folder in Outlook 2003 generates Compile Error User-Defined type not defined

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I save items I receive on my hard drive and name them differently.

Trying to import the items back into Outlook gives me an error:

> Compile Error User-Defined type not defined.

on

> Dim Savefolder As Outlook.Folder

In my first module

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Savefolder As String
    Savefolder = "c:\temp"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        stFileName = Savefolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        i = 0
JumpHere:
        If Dir(stFileName) = "" Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile stFileName
        Else
            i = i + 1
            stFileName = Savefolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName & " - " & i
            GoTo JumpHere
        End If
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

In my second module

```
Sub ImportMessagesInFolder()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim SourceFolderName As String
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.file
    Dim strFile, strFileType As String
    Dim oMsg As Object
    Dim copiedMsg As MailItem
    Dim Savefolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
'Source folder
    SourceFolderName = "C:\temp"
    Set SourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

'Set the Outlook folder name
    Set Savefolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Extra")
    Set Savefolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

        Set oMsg = Session.OpenSharedItem(FileItem.Path)
        On Error Resume Next

        Set copiedMsg = oMsg.Copy
        copiedMsg.Move Savefolder

        Set copiedMsg = Nothing
        oMsg.Delete
        Set oMsg = Nothing

    Next FileItem

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Outlook.MAPIFolder` instead.

Comment: This fixed my issue but now i get an issue with line :Set oMsg = Session.OpenSharedItem(FileItem.Path) 
it states when running the macro: Run time error438 object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Outlook 2003 @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: OpenSharedItem was introduced in Outlook 2007 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Well that's definitely the issue...Is there a way on 2003 to do what i am trying to do. Would Session.Getfolder work? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: In case of Outlook 2003 it is either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi - see OpenIMsgOnIStg) or Redemption and its RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile method.

Comment: How about without downloading a 3rd party app since i don't have administrator permissions? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: Sure, your script can use Redemption (which exposes RDOMail.Import and RDOSesion.GetMessageFromMsgFile)

Comment: BTW, installing and using Redemption does not require admin rights. Your other options are installing a newer version of Outlook or switching to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only).

Comment: I downloaded it at first and couldn't get it to work but that's because the path file wasn't in the right location. I got it to download yesterday and added it to my references but now I just need to formulate it in my code to get it all to work. @Dmitry Streblechenko